# Highcharts display column category names on the xaxis

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue displaying the column categories on the xaxis. I can get them to display in the "legend" and the "tooltips".
I have searched for a solution with no result. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
chart: {
renderTo: 'container',
type: 'column',
marginRight: 130,
marginBottom: 25
},
title: {
text: '',
x: -20 //center
},
subtitle: {
text: '',
x: -20
},

xAxis: {
categories: ['Detractors','Passives','Promoters','Not used']
},


yAxis: {
endOnTick: false,
max:101,
showFirstLabel: false,
lineColor:'#999',
lineWidth:1,
tickColor:'#666',
tickWidth:1,
tickLength:2,
tickInterval: 30,
gridLineColor:'#ddd',
title: {
text: 'Percentage %',
style: {
fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
color: '#000000',
fontWeight: 'bold',
fontSize: '8px'
}
},


},

tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return 'Guest responses:<br/> '+ this.y +'%<br/>'+ this.series.name +'<br/>';
}
},

legend: {
enabled: true,
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -10,
y: 100,
borderWidth: 0
},

colors: ['#FF0000','#FF6600','#009900','#333333'],

plotOptions: {
column: {
colorByPoint: false
},

series: {
cursor: 'pointer',
pointWidth: 20,
point: {
events: {
//click: function() {
}
},

legendIndex:0,

dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
color: '#000000',
align: 'center',
cursor: 'pointer',
//borderRadius: 5,
//backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 255, 255)',
//borderWidth: 1,
//borderColor: '#AAA',
y: -6,
format: '{y:.1f} %', // one decimal
y: -20, // 10 pixels down from the top
style: {
textShadow: false,
fontSize: '8px',
fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
},
formatter: function() {
return '<b>Guest responses: '+ this.y +'<br/>'+ this.series.name +'%</b>';
}
}
}

},

credits: {
enabled: false
},

lang: {
noData: "No data"
},
noData: {
style: {
fontWeight: 'normal',
fontSize: '12px',
color: '#303030'
}
},

navigation: {
buttonOptions: {
enabled: false
}
},

series: []
}

$.getJSON("../charts/1-2-4-reports_chart.php?TAG=<?php echo $_SESSION['SectionVar'];?>&From=<?php echo $_SESSION['StartDate'];?>&To=<?php echo $_SESSION['EndDate'];?>", function(json) {
options.xAxis.categories = json[0];
options.series[0] = json[0];
options.series[1] = json[1];
options.series[2] = json[2];
options.series[3] = json[3];
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});

Many thanks in advance for your time.
```

Comment: How your JSON looks? Could you please prepare minimal working example of your issue?

Comment: Can you show what your output looks like and how it differs from the output you want. That will help to analyse the problem better. some working example in jsfiddle.net also works fine.

Comment: My json looks like;[{"name":"Detractors","data":[15]},{"name":"Passives","data":[32.5]},{"name":"Promoters","data":[52.5]},{"name":"Not used","data":[2.5]}]

Comment: My attempt a creating a jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/Blackbox/zyandf9b/

Comment: It looks that you are overriding your categories in your json. Changed code: http://jsfiddle.net/zyandf9b/2/

Comment: @Grzegorz Blachliński Hi and thanks for your help and time. Your jsfiddle is fine but that is hard coding the categories and data. In a live running version the categories and data are called in the $.getJSON statement. So how can I use the results of that to populate the xaxis category lables.

Comment: Hi DCJones, I was just using your JSON file and fixing some issues I found. It would be great if you could show your whole JSON (with categories) so I can check how you should be able to create your chart

Comment: This is the complete json result: [{"name":"Detractors","data":[15]},{"name":"Passives","‌​data":[32.5]},{"name‌​":"Promoters","data"‌​:[52.5]},{"name":"No‌​t used","data":[2.5]}]

Comment: I think that loading your data using getJSON is not so different from loading this data using some variable. http://jsfiddle.net/zyandf9b/3/ Example that is more similar to your case. Hope this will help you with your issue.

Comment: @Grzegorz Blachliński  Hi, how would I incorrporate my call to the JSON script in your fidle. I.E.$.getJSON("../charts/1-2-4-reports_chart.php?TAG=<?php echo $_SESSION['SectionVar'];?>&From=<?php echo $_SESSION['StartDate'];?>&To=<?php echo $_SESSION['EndDate'];?>". Many thanks again.

Comment: You should be able to use similar approach to shown in below jsFiddle (I don't think it will work in jsFiddle though) http://jsfiddle.net/zyandf9b/4/ You can also find some information about custom preprocessing in Highcharts API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing

Comment: @Grzegorz Blachliński Many thanks for all your help. I have tried all ways to display the xaxis labels but with no success.  I have tried following your last jsfiddle using it as an example, but no joy.